# Update nested sets when changing parent or deleting

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update, nested-sets

I have the following table structure, which is [also on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8080f) for convenience:

```
+---------+-----------+---------+----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------------+--------+--------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| rule_id | parent_id | left_id | right_id | rule_type | rule_title        | rule_description                  | public | parse_bbcode | parse_links | parse_smilies | group_ids |
+---------+-----------+---------+----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------------+--------+--------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|       1 |         0 |       1 |        6 | cat       | Sample Category 1 |                                   |      1 |            0 |           0 |             0 | 1 2 7     |
|       2 |         1 |       2 |        3 | rule      | Sample Rule 1     | This is a sample rule description |      1 |            1 |           1 |             1 | 1 2 7     |
|       3 |         0 |       7 |        8 | cat       | Sample category 2 |                                   |      1 |            0 |           0 |             0 | 1 7 2     |
|       4 |         0 |       9 |       10 | cat       | Sample category 3 |                                   |      1 |            0 |           0 |             0 | 1 7 2     |
|       5 |         1 |       4 |        5 | rule      | Sample rule 3     | lol                               |      1 |            1 |           1 |             1 | 1 2 7     |
+---------+-----------+---------+----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------------+--------+--------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
```

As you see, `rule_type` can be either `'cat'` or `'rule'`.

`cat` stands for **category**, and categories are root nodes: so `parent_id` is always `0`.  In my code, we can identify categories by checking either if `rule_type = 'cat'` or `parent_id = 0`.

You can also see that I am using nested sets for my project and this is where the problem stands.

I have successfully created functions that:

- move rules & categories up or down; and
- put a new rule or category in the end of their respective place.

BUT I am failing to set the **RULES'** `right_id` & `left_id` if we change its `parent_id`! I'm also failing to set `right_id` & `left_id` if we delete a rule OR category.

#### Example

I'll try to explain with an example.  Note that this is just an example, not the actual case and I need a general answer.

From the table above, we see that we have 3 categories with `rule_id IN (1, 3, 4)` and two rules with `rule_id IN (2, 5)`.

The **rule** with `rule_id = 2` is part of the category with `rule_id = 1`, we can see that from the `parent_id` column.  What if I change the `parent_id` to 4?  How would the `right_id` & `left_id` get set so everything is in place again?  I know we need to update both `rule_id IN (1, 4)` to reorder everything, but I don't know how my query would look like.

Same goes for deleting... For example I delete `rule_id = 2` (which is a **rule**), how would I set `right_id` & `left_id` for `parent_id = 1` in the correct order? Or when I delete a category? How would I reorder the categories?

I didn't really try doing anything here, as I have no vision how I would do such a thing, therefore I'm asking for your help, folks.

I hope I made myself clear. If not, let me know and I'll try to be even more descriptive.

Comment: This may help: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: @prodigitalson Thanks, but it doesn't suffice.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why are you trying to do this with one table instead of two tables like `rules` and `rule_categories`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you have successfully set up the PDO connection.

Also, be aware the following examples only work if all the categories are root nodes (like in the subject). It's not a problem to change this code to work with nested categories.

**Deleting a rule**

1. Retrieve its `right_id` and `left_id` value.
2. Delete row from the database.
3. Update the table set `right_id` - 2 where `right_id` greater then the `right_id` of deleting rule.
4. Same for `left_id`

*Example:*

```
    $ruleIdForDel = 2;
    $leftId = 2;
    $rightId = 3;

    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $pdo->exec("DELETE FROM rules WHERE rule_id = $ruleIdForDel");
        $pdo->exec("UPDATE rules
                    SET left_id = CASE
                            WHEN left_id > $leftId THEN left_id - 2
                            ELSE left_id
                        END,
                        right_id = CASE
                            WHEN right_id > $rightId THEN right_id - 2
                            ELSE right_id
                        END");
        $pdo->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $pdo->rollBack();
        throw $e;
    }
```

**Updating rule's `parent_id`**

Suppose we are going to move node to the last position of new parent

1. Retrieve updating rule's `left_id` and `right_id` (`$ruleLeftId` and `$ruleRightId`)
2. Retrieve new parent rule's `left_id` and `right_id` (`$newParentRuleLeftId` and `$newParentRuleRightId`)
3. Check wether a node moving up or down the tree and depending on it generate new `left_id` and `right_id` values for the updating rule (`$ruleNewLeftId` and `$ruleNewRightId`)
4. Update rules `left_id` and `right_id` depending on the updating rule's destination
5. Update `parent_id`, `left_id`, `right_id` of the updating rule

If the updating rule's `right_key` less then new parent rule's `right_id` then the rule moves down the tree, otherwise it moves up the tree.

If the rule moves down the tree we are going to shift `left_id` value by minus 2 on the rules located between the updating rule's `left_id` (`$ruleLeftId`) and new `left_id` (`$ruleNewLeftId`) + 1. Otherwise, shift `left_id` value by 2 on the rules located between new `left_id` ($ruleNewLeftId) and initial `left_id` (`$ruleLeftId`).

Same for `right_id`.

*Example:*

```
    // Updating rule
    $ruleId = 2;
    $ruleLeftId = 2;
    $ruleRightId = 3;

    // New parent rule
    $newParentRuleId = 3;
    $newParentRuleLeftId = 7;
    $newParentRuleRightId = 8;


    // Generate new rule's left and right keys
    // Moves up
    if ($newParentRuleRightId < $ruleRightId) {
        $ruleNewLeftId = $newParentRuleRightId;
        $ruleNewRightId = $newParentRuleRightId + 1;
    // Moves down
    } else {
        $ruleNewLeftId = $newParentRuleRightId - 2; // 6
        $ruleNewRightId = $newParentRuleRightId - 1; // 7
    }

    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $pdo->exec("UPDATE rules
                            SET left_id = CASE
                                /* Moves down */
                                WHEN $ruleNewRightId > $ruleRightId AND
                                     left_id > $ruleLeftId AND
                                     left_id <= $ruleNewLeftId + 1 THEN left_id - 2
                                /* Moves up */
                                WHEN $ruleNewRightId < $ruleRightId AND
                                     left_id >= $ruleNewLeftId AND
                                     left_id < $ruleLeftId THEN left_id + 2
                                ELSE left_id
                            END,
                            right_id = CASE
                                WHEN $ruleNewRightId > $ruleRightId AND
                                     right_id > $ruleRightId AND
                                     right_id <= $ruleNewRightId THEN right_id - 2
                                WHEN $ruleNewRightId < $ruleRightId AND
                                     right_id >= $ruleNewLeftId AND
                                     right_id <= $ruleRightId THEN right_id + 2
                                ELSE right_id
                            END");
        $pdo->exec("UPDATE rules
                    SET parent_id = $newParentRuleId,
                        left_id = $ruleNewLeftId,
                        right_id = $ruleNewRightId
                    WHERE rule_id = $ruleId");
        $pdo->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $pdo->rollBack();
        throw $e;
    }
```

I didnt use any `PDO::Statement` just to save space.

I have not tested it properly so post an issue if you find some.

Comment: Thank you. I only had to read through your description, that was the only part I was unable to do, the logic behind deleting and updating.

Answer (score 1):

> The rule with rule_id = 2 is part of the category with rule_id = 1, we
>   can see that from the parent_id column. What if I change the parent_id
>   to 4? How would the right_id & left_id get set so everything is in
>   place again? I know we need to update both rule_id IN (1, 4) to
>   reorder everything, but I don't know how my query would look like.

Try something like this, i haven't tested it yet, but it might get you on the right track

```
UPDATE table SET parent_id = 4, 
                 right_id = (CASE WHEN parent_id = 4 THEN 1 END), 
                 left_id = (CASE WHEN parent_id = 4 THEN 2 END)
```

Comment: Nope that did not get me in the right track at all. Also note what I said in the first post: "I'll try to explain with an example. Note that this is just an example, not the actual case and I need a general answer.". Thanks anyway.